# Mapster is not mapping properties inside derived classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mapster

I have the following entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public required string FullName { get; set; }
}
public class Visitor : Person
{
    public required string CarNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following dtos:

```
public class PersonInfo
{
    public required string FullName { get; set; }
}
public class VisitorInfo : PersonInfo
{
    public required string CarNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And I configured Mapping like this:

```
        TypeAdapterConfig<Person, PersonInfo>().NewConfig()
        .Include<Visitor, VisitorInfo>();
```

When I got people from Ef core **CarNumber** was not mapped even though I checked it exists.